# MFC: How to use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() from the main thread to wait for multiple threads to complete that use SendMessage()?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have a main thread that fires off several other threads to complete various items of work based on what the user choose from the main UI.   Normally I'd use `WaitForMultipleObjects()` with *bWaitAll* set to TRUE.  However, in this case those other threads will log output to another window that uses a mutex to ensure the threads only output one at a time.  Part of that process uses `SendMessage()` to send get the text size and send the text to the windows which will hang if using `WaitForMultipleObjects()` since it's running from the main UI thread.  So I moved over to use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` with `QS_SENDMESSAGE` flag, only it's problem is the logic for *bWaitAll* which states it will only return if all objects are signaled **AND** an input event occurred (instead of returning when all objects are signaled **OR** an input event occurred).  Had the logic been **OR** this should have worked:

```
  DWORD waitres=WAIT_FAILED;

  while (1)
  {
    MSG msg;
    while (::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE)) {
      // mfc message pump
      if (!theApp.PumpMessage()) {
        // program end request
        // TO DO
      }
    }
    // MFC idel processing
    LONG lidlecount = 0;
    while (theApp.OnIdle(lidlecount++));
    // our wait
    waitres = ::MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(threadcount, threadhandles, TRUE, INFINITE, QS_SENDMESSAGE);
    // check if ended due to message
    if (waitres!=WAIT_OBJECT_0+threadcount) {
      // no, exit loop
      break;
    }
  }
```

Rather than fire off a thread that then fires off the other threads I wondered what is the correct way to handle this from the main thread?  I thought about using *bWaitAll* FALSE then using `WaitForMultipleObjects()` with *bWaitAll* set to TRUE and the *dwMilliseconds* set to 0 (or 1) and checking the result to see if completed.  If not, it would need to loop back to the top of the loop and then to `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` which when using *bWaitAll* FALSE could return right away if one of the many threads completed (say 1 thread of 10 completed, I could check as mentioned above if all completed, but when going back with *bWaitAll* FALSE it will just return and not wait).

So what is the proper way to handle waiting for multiple threads (that use `SendMessage()`) to complete in the main thread of an MFC application?

Thanks.

Comment: Using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` with `bWaitAll=FALSE` is the correct solution. Put the thread handles into an array, and each time the wait indicates a thread is finished, remove that thread from the array. Keep looping until the array is empty. Pump the message queue whenever the wait indicates pending messages.

Comment: in general - yes, you never must use bWaitAll set to TRUE. use `bWaitAll=FALSE` and change wait array if need. in case thread/processes - of course remove handles from array after it signal. but for concrete task - all solution is wrong. you not need wait for thread handles. you need create common structure for task with ref count. when thread exit - it release ref count. when structure destroyed (no more threads) post message to your window

Answer (score 1):

> So what is the proper way to handle waiting for multiple threads to
> complete

need create some structure, with reference count and pass pointer to this structure to every thread. here also probably exist sense have some common task data. and *HWND* of some window in main(GUI) thread. when worked thread exit - it release reference on object. when last thread exit - delete object and post some message to window, from main thread.

so we not need store thread handles (can just close it) and wait om multiple handles. instead we got some window message when all thread finish task

example of code

```
struct Task 
{
    HWND _hwnd;
    LONG _dwRefCount = 1;
    // some common task data probably ..

    Task(HWND hwnd) : _hwnd(hwnd) {}

    ~Task() {
        PostMessageW(_hwnd, WM_USER, 0, 0);// WM_USER as demo only
    }

    void AddRef(){
        InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&_dwRefCount);
    }

    void Release(){
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_dwRefCount)) delete this;
    }
};

ULONG CALLBACK WorkThread(void* pTask)
{
    WCHAR sz[16];
    swprintf_s(sz, _countof(sz), L"%x", GetCurrentThreadId());
    MessageBoxW(0, L"working...", sz, MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK);
    reinterpret_cast<Task*>(pTask)->Release();
    return 0;
}

void StartTask(HWND hwnd, ULONG n)
{
    if (Task* pTask = new Task(hwnd))
    {
        do 
        {
            pTask->AddRef();

            if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, WorkThread, pTask, 0, 0))
            {
                CloseHandle(hThread);
            }
            else
            {
                pTask->Release();
            }
        } while (--n);

        pTask->Release();
    }
}
```